# What are update-rc runlevel links?

Tags: ssh, startup, configuration, services

I'm creating a simple script to edit a raspberry pi SD card to enable SSH (I know it can be done in other ways but I need to do it with update-rc). I'm searching for what happens when I run `update-rc ssh enable`, here's what is written in the manuals:

```
   When run with the enable [ S|2|3|4|5 ]  options,  update-rc.d  modifies
   existing  runlevel  links  for  the script /etc/init.d/name by renaming
   stop links to start links with a sequence number equal to the  positive
   difference  of current sequence number minus 100, thus returning to the
   original sequence number that the script had been installed with before
   disabling it.
```

What are those runlevel links and sequence numbers and what are them form? I did `ls -la /etc/rc2.d` and all I could see was a simply link to `/init.d/ssh`. How to modify these runlevel links and sequence numbers?

Comment: That is really old documentation. Depending on your version of Ubuntu you are using either upstart or systemd

Comment: @bodhi.zazen its the latest raspbian (raspberry pi debian based). It has the scripts in the rc.d folders and the raspi-config script, which is the script that activates ssh on raspberry pi, uses update-rc as the command

Comment: A long time ago, in a galaxy far far away there was a concept known as System V with these runlevels of which you speak - https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/linux-runlevels-explained/ . Even in Ubuntu, runlevels 2-5 have been the same out of the box for a long long long time. The run levels are sort of in /etc.rcX.d and are links back to /etc/init.d, the init scripts for the various services. All update-rc really did in those days, for the most part, was add / remove the links so you did not need to do so manually.  See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

Comment: As Ubuntu migrated to upstart and now systemd those system V scripts have been replaced by upstart and systemd init scripts with different syntax. I do not know what raspberry pi / debian is doing with those scripts. Perhaps ask on Debian or Pi forums. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42933/how-to-find-out-the-default-init-system-of-my-raspbian so, again depends on the version you are running, but it is possible any scripts in /etc/init.d have yet to be fully converted to systemd.

Comment: So basically, under System V, if say samba or apache is dependent of networking scripts, networking scripts would be given a lower number and thus run first, then samba or apache with a higher sequence. Each run level could have a different set of services running.

Comment: See https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html / and http://www.linuxvoodoo.com/resources/howtos/sysvinit

Comment: @bodhi.zazen my raspberry, according to stat /sbin/init, uses systemd. How is it possible if the ssh have rc.d scripts. And raspi-config, when it wants to enable ssh, uses update-rc and not systemd commands

Comment: Because raspberry is in the process of converting to systemd and sysdemd has a backwards compatibility functionality until all the scripts are converted . see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts or similar.